# ImageJ - Cumulative histograms and Histograms

Tags: java, image-processing, histogram, imagej

I have run into a small problem with my program as it seems unable to find the highest value in a histogram to calculate the scale the histogram is supposed to be so now the entire histogram is way out of bounds

I really hope someone can help me out since it's driving me crazy

```
import ij.*;
import ij.process.*;
import ij.gui.*;
import java.awt.*;
import ij.plugin.filter.*;

public class Oblig3_Oppg2 implements PlugInFilter {

    public int setup(String arg, ImagePlus im) {;
        return DOES_8G + NO_CHANGES;
    }

    public void run(ImageProcessor ip) {
        final int W = 256;
        final int H = 100;
        final int H1 = 140;
        int[] hist = ip.getHistogram();
        int[] KH = new int[W]; //Cumulative Histogram Array


        int maxVal;

        //Calculates the highest pixel count in the Histogram

        for (int i = 0; i < W; i++){
            if (hist[i] > maxVal){
                maxVal = i;
            }
        }

        KH[0] = hist[0];

        for(int i = 1; i < W; i++) {
            KH[i] = KH[i-1] + hist[i];
        }

        ImageProcessor histIp = new ByteProcessor(W, H1);
        histIp.setValue(255);
        histIp.fill();

        int max = KH[255];


        for(int j = 0; j < W; j++){
            KH[j] = (KH[j]*100)/max;  //Scales the Cumulative Histogram
            hist[j] = (hist[j]*100)/maxVal; // Scales the Histogram
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < W; k++){
            histIp.setValue(0);
            histIp.drawLine(k, H, k, H-KH[k]);
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < W; k++){
            histIp.setValue(0);
            histIp.drawLine(k, H, k, H-hist[k]);
        }

        for (int l = 0; l < W; l++){
            histIp.setValue(l);
            histIp.drawLine(l, 140, l, 102);
        }
        histIp.setValue(0);
        histIp.drawLine(W, H, W, 0);

        // Display the histogram image:

        String hTitle = "Histogram";
        ImagePlus histIm = new ImagePlus(hTitle, histIp);
        histIm.show();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set `maxVal` to the actual *value*, not the current *index* in your loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < W; i++){
    if (hist[i] > maxVal){
        maxVal = hist[i]; // <-- here
    }
}
```

Furthermore, it might be better to limit the loop to `hist.length` instead of `W`. That would prevent errors in case you set `W` to some value different from the array length that `ip.getHistogram()` returns.

Since you don't provide a runnable example (i.e. the entire Java class; I assume you implement `ij.plugin.filter.PlugInFilter`), I didn't test the code, and it's not entirely clear to me what you want to achieve.

Comment: I've updated the example to a runnable one. What I want to achieve is that the histogram is scaled down to a resonable size.. e.g  if maxVal = 532 then the program scales it according to that so that the highest bare of the histogram always reach 100 in height :)